# Material-UI TextField state incorrect after uncontrolled value change with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a Material-UI TextField element as below

```
<TextField
    variant='outlined' fullWidth
    name={'webhook'}
    label={'Webhook URL'}
    defaultValue={state.webhook}
    error={errors.webhook !== undefined}
    helperText={errors.webhook && 'Not a valid webhook URL.'}
    inputRef={register({
        required: true,
    })}
/>
```

And I control the value of the input using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/api#register).  It says as per the documentation that it is to be used with uncontrolled inputs as it controls the value of it through the useForm props.

So when I set the value from the default value of `''` (empty string) to an actual value provided by a variable (non-empty string) using `setValue` from `useForm()`, the input label overlays the text in the center of the textfield instead of moving to the top as it would with an input that has a value.

Modifying the value of the field after the input's value gets set will make it work properly, but I need it to recognize that the value changed without modifying the value.

How can I get it to properly recognize that the value of the input has changed?

Example of image in glitched state:

[image: Example of image in glitched state]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a look at Controller: https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller

here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-079xx

```
<Controller name="test" control={control} as={TextField} />
```